# How to find total count of distinct items along with item using Room?

Tags: android-room

Let's say I have a table `kids_data`

| id | kid_name | father_name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Alisa | Bosconovitch |
| 2 | Ebby | Bosconovitch |
| 3 | John | Peter |
| 4 | simmy | Alladin |
| 5 | sara | Alladin |

Now I want to fetch distinct names and their count too.

So if I perform

```
SELECT DISTINCT father_name from kids_data
```

What I will get is

| father_name |
| --- |
| Bosconovitch |
| Peter |
| Alladin |

I want count of each kid too.

As Bosconovitch & Alladin have Two children then I want that number also.

Using Room Database in Android? How?

My class is

```
data class FatherData(
    val kid_count: Int,
    val father_name: String
)
```

In Dao

```
// what Query or how can i do this to achieve that, please.
@Query("SELECT DISTINCT father_name from kids_data")
fun getFatherData(): List<FatherData>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This does what I wanted!

This query will be used.

```
@Query("select father_name, count(father_name) as kid_count from kids_data group by father_name")
fun getFatherData(): List<FatherData>
```